# How do I stop Android ProgressBar Circle?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, widget, progress-bar

I've got an app that should show the Android ProgressBar circle when it is processing some input. Right now I just make it invisible when it isn't busy, but I'd like it to still show a motionless progress circle when not busy.

How do I get the Android ProgressBar circle to stop moving but still be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a means within the APIs to make it not move. My guess is that you'd have to "fake" it by grabbing your own copy of the drawables that make up the progress circles and display one of them in an ImageView.